# Site is Not Working When I connect Local Database In MVC5 Project,

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I Have create MVC5 Project. its Working well when its connect server database.after I have created table  same database  and connected with  my project local SQL server configuration. after that Run my Project its showing Error Like this 
Server Error in '/' Application.

```
Login failed for user ''.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user ''.

Source Error: 


Line 70:                 if (parameters != null)
Line 71:                 {
Line 72:                     result = await db.QueryAsync<TModel>(sql: procname, param: BuildQueryParameter(parameters), commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
Line 73:                 }
Line 74:                 else

Source File: C:\MVC5_Full_Version\Inspinia_MVC5\Data\Base\HomeSqlDBRepository.cs  Line: 72 


[SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user ''.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling) +970
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +802
```

showing Error Like after comment Local db un comment server db its Working . i have Configured  local and server db using Appsettings.config

Here Code of App Settings code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<appSettings>

  <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
  <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
  <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
  <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
  <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />

  <add key="DefaultMembershipName" value="UserName" />

  <add key="SmtpServer" value="relay-hosting.secureserver.net" />
  <add key="SmtpPort" value="25" />
  <add key="UserId" value="thenna41@gmail.com" />
  <add key="Password" value="pixel@1990" />

  <add key="DefaultTheme" value="Theme1"/>
  <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
  <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
  <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
  <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  <!--<add key="Tickandtie" value="Server=123.324.3434.34;Database=montage;User ID=Montage;Password=qbZ4c7?3;Trusted_Connection=False;"/>-->
  <add key="Tickandtie" value="Server=DESKTOP-QD6A981\SQLEXPRESS;Database=montage;Integrated Security=sspi;Trusted_Connection=False;"/>
  <add key="CustomAuthentication.LoginUrl" value="/Account/LogOn" />
  <add key="CustomAuthentication.Cookie.Name" value=".CUSTOM_AUTH" />
  <add key="CustomAuthentication.Cookie.Expiration" value="1" />
  <add key="CustomAuthentication.Cookie.Timeout" value="20" />
</appSettings>
```

And Web.config

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  Więcej informacji dotyczących konfigurowania aplikacji platformy ASP.NET można znaleźć na stronie
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 --></configSections>
  <connectionStrings>

  <add name="Montagenew" connectionString="data source=DESKTOP-QD6A981\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=montagenew;Integrated Security=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
 <!--<add name="montageEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Entityframework.Model1.csdl|res://*/Entityframework.Model1.ssdl|res://*/Entityframework.Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=DESKTOP-QD6A981\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=montage;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />--></connectionStrings>


  <system.web>
    <trust level="Full" />
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <authentication mode="Windows">

      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Index" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.5.1" debug="true" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
  <sessionState timeout="40" mode="InProc" cookieless="false" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff2" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.2.0" newVersion="5.2.2.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
 <appSettings configSource="AppSettings.config" />
<system.net>
  <mailSettings>
    <smtp from="thenna4@gmail.com">
      <network host="smtp-mail.outlook.com" 
               port="587" 
               userName="thenna41@gmail.com"
               password="pixel@1990" 
               enableSsl="true" />
    </smtp>
  </mailSettings>
</system.net>
</configuration>
```

where did mistake any one help me?  thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like a problem with your connection string in Web.Config. Try setting integrated security=true if your current login is accepted by sql server. otherwise, you will need to provide a valid username and password in this connection string.